# How to solve this Poisson-distribution question?

Tags: poisson-distribution

The weight of certain type of muffin is approximately
50 grams. Let X be the number of muffins that weigh more than 50 grams has the probability of 0.005. A sample of 100 muffins are selected randomly.

Show that the distribution of muffin that weigh more than 50 gram satisfies Poisson approximation to binomial distribution.

Comment: The phrase "Let X be the number of muffins that weigh more than 50 grams has the probability of 0.005."  is hard to interpret.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is not clear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit for clarity.  When you do that, also include a sense of your efforts.  What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?